# ms SQL join multiple row into multitple column

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I'm not sure whether to use pivot or not because i'm getting confuse on it. i got some sample data at [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87e91/1/0)

the result that i'm looking for is(doesn't matter null or empty string if empty record)

```
 Name   Product m1SALES m1STARGET m1GROWTH m2SALES m2STARGET m2GROWTH m3SALES m3STARGET M3GROWTH
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 John   A 5 100   5        10      100       10       NULL    NULL       NULL
 John    B  NULL    NULL      NULL     NULL    NULL      NULL     20      100    20
```

I only need a quarter records at any point of time. 1,2,3 OR 4,5,6 OR 7,8,9 OR 10,11,12. 
where by the month+year is depends on the data, it might be no sales record on certain month.

i tried select the data depends on month + year from the same table 3 times, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit primitive but will do the job without pivot :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        name ,
        product ,
        ( SELECT    sales
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 1
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m1sales ,
        ( SELECT    starget
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 1
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m1starget ,
        ( SELECT    growth
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 1
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m1growth ,
        ( SELECT    sales
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 2
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m2sales ,
        ( SELECT    starget
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 2
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m2starget ,
        ( SELECT    growth
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 2
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m2growth ,
        ( SELECT    sales
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 3
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m3sales ,
        ( SELECT    starget
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 3
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m3starget ,
        ( SELECT    growth
          FROM      yourtable b
          WHERE     a.product = b.product
                    AND MONTH = 3
                    AND YEAR = 2014
        ) m3growth
FROM    yourtable a
```

Comment: Sweet!! and also by adding a.name = b.name, if there are different name appear in the list.